# Preoperative thrombocytosis may identify patients who are at greater risk or risks of x, y, and/or z?

Tags: grammatical-number

> Preoperative thrombocytosis may identify patients who are at greater **risk** for advanced disease, unfavorable grade histology, and recurrence.

There are several potential risks.
Should it be *risk* or *risks*?

Comment: Do you mean that to be "advanced disease,  unfavorable grade histology, AND recurrence"--or do you mean it to be "advanced disease,  unfavorable grade histology, OR recurrence"? You need to choose one of those two possible coordinating conjunctions (either "and" or "or") to end the list of outcomes being discussed.

Comment: and - does it make a difference in risk or risks?

Comment: Patients might *face risks* or *be at risk*.

Either way, neither would be *for*; only *of* or *from*.

*This is a risk for people* is too different from *people are at risk for (anything)*.

Whether it should be *… histology, and recurrence* depends on how many conditions or risks are being listed.

*1) advanced disease
2) unfavorable grade histology
3) recurrence* or what, please?

Comment: I [posted a question](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10822/procedure-for-dividing-a-complex-question-into-separate-questions) to the meta forum concerning the original question here.

Comment: @Robbie Goodwin Try a Google Ngram on "at risk for" and "at risk of".  And I'd say recurrence of what is obvious--the original disease, post op thrombocytosis.

Comment: Really, Xanne? Did you doubt me, then?

Answer (score 3):

Use *at ... risk* even if multiple possible consequences are listed. See the example I've shown in the following dictionary entry:

> **at risk** *phrase*
>   Exposed to harm or danger.
>   ‘Children who use mobile phones are at risk of memory loss, sleeping disorders and other health problems.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/at_risk)